# Flutter OTP dots placeholders UI

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to implement an OTP UI like the one in the following image with Flutter:

[image: required_ui]

The idea is that the keyboard and placeholder `gray` dots would be always shown and when the user enters a number, the corresponding placeholder dot color should be changed to `blue`.

I want know how to implement the logic of changing the placeholder dot color depending on the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described logic can be implemented with a variable to store the OTP code and then use it to determine the color of the placeholder dot depending on the length of the currently entered OTP.

I have created a demo example in this [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=aa9fdd892cc063be7f10f681addf81f1) which implements the same described logic, you can run it directly from `DartPad`.

[image: flutter_otp_dots_placeholders_ui_demo]